# How do I remove the unwanted text from bibliography in natbib?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I am using natbib package on Overleaf. "Pages 2" isn't mentioned anywhere in my .bib file. I am using plainnat style. How do I remove this?

Consider the following segments in .bib file for references 2 and 3 in the image:

```
@Article{Ghavamzadeh2016survey,
  author       = {Mohammad Ghavamzadeh and Shie Mannor and Joelle Pineau and Aviv Tamar},
  date         = {2016-09-14},
  journaltitle = {Foundations and Trends in Machine Learning, Vol. 8: No. 5-6, pp 359-492, 2015},
  title        = {Bayesian Reinforcement Learning: A Survey},
  doi          = {10.1561/2200000049},
  eprint       = {1609.04436},
  eprintclass  = {cs.AI},
  eprinttype   = {arXiv},
  year = {2016},
  number       = {5-6},
  pages        = {359--483},
  volume       = {8},
  file         = {:http\://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04436v1:PDF},
  groups       = {Bayesian RL},
  keywords     = {cs.AI, cs.LG, stat.ML},
  publisher    = {Now Publishers},
}

@Book{Hawkins2005,
  author    = {Hawkins, Jeff},
  date      = {2005},
  title     = {On intelligence},
  isbn      = {9780805078534},
  location  = {New York},
  publisher = {Henry Holt and Co},
  groups    = {Cognitive Science},
  year      = {2005},
}
```

I am using the following 'include.tex' file. Maybe something he is interfering with natbib?

```
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2.0cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{natbib} % for bibliography
\usepackage{tabularx,longtable,multirow,subfigure,caption}%hangcaption
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} % page layout
\usepackage{url} % URLs
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{epstopdf} % automatically replace .eps with .pdf in graphics
\usepackage{backref} % needed for citations
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{accessibility}
\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref,hypertexnames=false,colorlinks]{hyperref}
```

[image]

Other than this, I use

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

at the beginning of the main file.

I hope that this helps. I do not know how to make an equivalent minimal reproducible for this.

Comment: please make a compilable [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if your bib style does not happen to be exactly what you need, I would use biblatex instead. Much easier to customise such small details.

Comment: Are your works referenced on page 2?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have added more information. I believe a minimal reproducible is difficult is this case. No they are not referenced on page 2.

Comment: Can you make ONE .tex file we can copy and paste without having to puzzle together multiple code blocks?

Comment: Just a guess: try without `pagebackref`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i have added an answer with what you asked. But oh, lemme try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pages xxx` is a reference back to the page where you cited the work. If you don't want this, don't request `backref` in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2.0cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{natbib} % for bibliography
\usepackage{tabularx,longtable,multirow,subfigure,caption}%hangcaption
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} % page layout
\usepackage{url} % URLs
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{epstopdf} % automatically replace .eps with .pdf in graphics
%\usepackage{backref} % needed for citations
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{accessibility}
\usepackage[pdftex,
%pagebackref,
hypertexnames=false,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Ghavamzadeh2016survey,
  author       = {Mohammad Ghavamzadeh and Shie Mannor and Joelle Pineau and Aviv Tamar},
  date         = {2016-09-14},
  journaltitle = {Foundations and Trends in Machine Learning, Vol. 8: No. 5-6, pp 359-492, 2015},
  title        = {Bayesian Reinforcement Learning: A Survey},
  doi          = {10.1561/2200000049},
  eprint       = {1609.04436},
  eprintclass  = {cs.AI},
  eprinttype   = {arXiv},
  year = {2016},
  number       = {5-6},
  pages        = {359--483},
  volume       = {8},
  file         = {:http\://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04436v1:PDF},
  groups       = {Bayesian RL},
  keywords     = {cs.AI, cs.LG, stat.ML},
  publisher    = {Now Publishers},
}

@Book{Hawkins2005,
  author    = {Hawkins, Jeff},
  date      = {2005},
  title     = {On intelligence},
  isbn      = {9780805078534},
  location  = {New York},
  publisher = {Henry Holt and Co},
  groups    = {Cognitive Science},
  year      = {2005},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\cite{Hawkins2005,Ghavamzadeh2016survey}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks. That worked. I guess it was a pretty straightforward solution. I lost my patience with this one. I would upvote but my reputation is low.

Comment: @ShubhamSubhnil You're welcome!